# ffmpeg can't extract all frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to extract all frames from a video.

I have tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -i battle1.avi outN-%d.png
```

This video is 15 FPS  with 45 seconds and I get this result:

```
 Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'outN-d.png'. Use '-frames:v 1' for a single image, or '-update' option, or use a pattern such as %03d within the filename.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

there is a way to solve ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In your batch file you need to escape the `%` with, ironically, a `%`:

```
ffmpeg -i battle1.avi outN-%%d.png
```